# iPhone & Ipad - UIGetScreenImage - how to capture in landscape?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

Apple recently decided to allow developers to use this UIGetScreenImage private API.

I have implemented it and it works fine in portrait, but when I run the device to landscape (self.view rotates) and UIGetScreenImage continues to capture using the screen non-rotated coordinates.

The result is a cropped landscape result.

UIGetScreenImage is the only method that works in my case, as far as I know and until you guys don't find an answer to [**this other question of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289948/iphone-is-it-impossible-to-grab-the-contents-of-a-calayers-composition) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to apply the rotation yourself.

`UIGetScreenImage()` doesn't care about the orientation. In fact it cannot, because there can be multiple UIWindows on screen while some are autorotated, some are not.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It was a typo in my code... now it is working fine.