# Apply CoreAnimation on image (not on screen)

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I was wondering if it's possible to use Core Animation to work on images and not on the display. For instance I want to apply a CATransform3D (on the iPhone) and output the result of the image manipulation in another image and not on the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: This question asks the same thing, in a different way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289948/iphone-is-it-impossible-to-grab-the-contents-of-a-calayers-composition

Comment: so it seems this is not really possible without grabbing the screen as a workaround...

Answer (score 1):

You need [Core Graphics transforms](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101) for that. Core Animation is all about the display.